# Movable Marker in Mapstraction using Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, mapstraction

I am trying to place a marker that can be moved (movable marker) using Mapstraction Google Maps v3. But I cannot find the right settings.

I can place a static marker. But cannot find the configuration for a movable marker. Any one has any thoughts on this?

Cheers,
RD

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you are using version 3.9 of the API)

Have you tried setting draggable to true in the constructor?

(Which takes):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

You could also look a bit further into the mouse event classes, the marker class has a SetPosition method, and mouse event has a OnMouseOver event or something to that degree and a OnMouseClick event, or something like that.

Now I have never worked with this API before and I dont do to much Javascript but il try 
to make some pseudo code.

Option A:

```
var default = new google.maps.MarkerOptions;
//Other setting's go here.//
default.draggable = true;
//For fun.//
default.raiseOnDrag = true;
//Example object.//
var marker = new google.maps.Marker( default );
```

I assume that this may make the object draggable.

Option B:

```
/*This function will check if we are going to move our marker and then do it if
the conditions are right.*/
function CheckMoveMarker( var marker )
{
   //Make a new mouse event.//
   mouseStuff = new google.maps.SomePseudoMouseEvent();

   //In the real API this was an event but I dident want to write one... :-P//
   if( mouseStuff.isOver( marker.getRect() ) == true ) {

      //You may want to pop a thread here.//
      while ( mouseStuff.mouseClicked() == true ) {

         /*You may need some clever way to get the position, perhaps through
         the "map" class: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation
         /javascript/reference#Map .*/

         marker.setPosition( mouseStuff.x, mouseStuff.y );
      }
   }

   //Return the changes to our marker.//
   return marker;
}


//Somewhere in your code.//
myMarker = CheckMoveMarker( myMarker );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @the-floating-brain. But your solution directly uses GMaps. It is not my intention to do so. I want to use GMaps via Mapstraction.

Comment: Mapstraction  does not support editing which, historically was because there wasn't consistent support amongst the map providers, thus defeating the object of the abstraction. If you require those features you should use the Google API directly.

Comment: @Rohitesh Sorry I just kinda clicked on the first thing that showed up on Google XD .